# JavaScript Confirm before deletion with PHP/MYSQL

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, confirm

I have tried a number of examples here but I can get my code to actually show a popup window before deletion. The code I use can be found here:

`echo "<td><button class='btn'><a href=\"deleteuserExecute2.php?login=" .$login. "\" onClick=\"return confirm(\'Delete this Account?\')\"; >DELETE ACCOUNT </a></button></td>";`

http://jsfiddle.net/mpogoro/EGfcY/

Comment: The JSFiddle embedded in the html in the question does not exist.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
      function ConfirmDelete()
      {
            if (confirm("Delete Account?"))
                 location.href='linktoaccountdeletion';
      }
  </script>


  echo '<input type="button" onclick="ConfirmDelete()" value="DELETE ACCOUNT">';
```

Comment: Bad idea. 'location.href' redirects the page (to another PHP) and Back button can't return you to the current PHP page.

Answer (score 22):

You just need to use the `onclick` method for your link or button:

```
<a href="DELETE_PAGE" onClick="return confirm('Delete This account?')">Delete Account</a>
```

Comment: Better than above. But you still have to hit Back button to return to the current page. Annoying, if not bad programming. (See my Ajax solution further below.)  ... Ooops! The question is unfortunately closed. I had a nice solution to give, but the system allows for **irresponsible closing of questions**!

Comment: ... irresponsible, unjustified and wrong closing of questions.

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
 <form action="url/to/delation_page" onSubmit="return confirm('are you sure?')">

</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just say

```
onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')"
         ^^^^^^ --> this is very important step...
```

Answer (score 1):

**javascript confirmation**

```
function doConfirm(id)
        {

            var ok = confirm("Are you sure to Delete?")
            if (ok)
            {

                if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                }
                else
                {// code for IE6, IE5
                    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }

                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
                {
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
                    {
                         window.location = "create_dealer.php";  // self page
                    }
                }

                xmlhttp.open("GET", "delete_dealer.php?id=" + id);
                xmlhttp.send();
            }
        }
```

**button for delete**

```
<input type="button" onclick="doConfirm();"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

if u use on-click the data will be deleted but to view result u have to refresh the page manually instead use
    onSubmit="return confirm('are you sure?')"

think it helps !