# Confirm button before running deleting routine from website

Tags: php, html

I have a page on my website that is dynamically created with information from an SQL database. As well as the data being displayed a delete link is also created for each record which links to a php file called deleteRecord.php that deletes that record from the database.

[image: Example of data listings]

Is there any way I can incorporate a confirmation message so that when the Delete link is clicked it will only run the deleteRecord.php file if the response is Yes?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16121538/javascript-confirm-before-deletion-with-php-mysql

Comment: You should also consider using jQuery's Ajax implementation for this - it would mean you don't have to navigate away from this page.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You could use JavaScript. Either put the code inline, into a function or use jQuery.

1. Inline:

   ```
   <a href="deletelink" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')">Delete</a>
   ```
2. In a function:

   ```
   <a href="deletelink" onclick="return checkDelete()">Delete</a>
   ```

   and then put this in `<head>`:

   ```
   <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
   function checkDelete(){
       return confirm('Are you sure?');
   }
   </script>
   ```

   This one has more work, but less file size if the list is long.
3. With jQuery:

   ```
   <a href="deletelink" class="delete">Delete</a>
   ```

   And put this in `<head>`:

   ```
   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
   <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $("a.delete").click(function(e){
           if(!confirm('Are you sure?')){
               e.preventDefault();
               return false;
           }
           return true;
       });
   });
   </script>
   ```

Comment: Excellent - thanks for your help. However in section 2 I you have two <script> lines. I didn't need these, just one <script>

Comment: @RichardGriffiths Yeah, I had accidentally put the jQuery `<script>` there. Moved it to #3.

Comment: In a PHP environment, the inline version may fail to work, throwing a syntax error. A simple workaround is to escape the single quotes in the confirmation message text: `onclick="return confirm(\'Are you sure?\')`

Comment: <a onclick="return confirm(\'Are you sure ?\')" href="'.base_url().'admin/delete_client/'.$id.'" id="'.$id.'" class="delete_client"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>

Comment: Fastest, easiest solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 options

1) Use javascript to confirm deletion (use onsubmit event handler), however if the client has JS disabled, you're in trouble.

2) Use PHP to echo out a confirmation message, along with the contents of the form (hidden if you like) as well as a submit button called "confirmation", in PHP check if `$_POST["confirmation"]` is set.

Answer (score 2):

**Call this function onclick of button**

```
/*pass whatever you want instead of id */
function doConfirm(id) {
    var ok = confirm("Are you sure to Delete?");
    if (ok) {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                window.location = "create_dealer.php";
            }
        }

        xmlhttp.open("GET", "delete_dealer.php?id=" + id);
        // file name where delete code is written
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with an `confirm()` message using Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      var baseUrl='http://example.com';
      function ConfirmDelete()
      {
            if (confirm("Delete Account?"))
                 location.href=baseUrl+'/deleteRecord.php';
      }
  </script>


  echo '<a type="button" onclick="ConfirmDelete()">DELETE ACCOUNT</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
<?php 
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","EmpDB") or die(mysqli_error($con));
 if(isset($_POST[add]))
 {
 $sno = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST[sno]);
   $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST[sname]);
   $course = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST[course]);
 
   $query = "insert into students(sno,name,course) values($sno,'$name','$course')";
   //echo $query;
   $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
   printf ("New Record has id %d.\n", mysqli_insert_id($con));
  mysqli_close($con);
   
 }  
?>
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>mysql_insert_id Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="POST">
Enter S.NO: <input type="text" name="sno"/><br/>
Enter Student Name: <input type="text" name="sname"/><br/>
Enter Course: <input type="text" name="course"/><br/>
<input type="submit" name="add" value="Add Student"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method using both onlcick & form submit button with php record id value (record to be delete).
Use php code to get the record ID to be deleted. This is working for me.

```
<form action="deleteRecord.php" method="POST">

    <button onclick="return confirm('Are you sure! want to delete?')" type="submit" name="id" value="<?=$record['id'];?>" >Delete</button>

</form>

deleteRecord.php example file
<?php 
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","dbname") or die(mysqli_error($con));
    if(isset($_POST['id']))
    {
        $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['id']);
        $query = "DELETE FROM table_name WHERE id='$id' ";
        $query_run = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    }
    mysqli_close($con);

    if($query_run)
    {
        echo "Deleted Successfully";
        exit(0);
    }
        else
    {
        echo "Not Deleted";
        exit(0);
    }
?>
```